# Why wont "parallax" effect work on un-fixed background image

Tags: html, css, image

When I add a background image to a div, the following div scrolls past the image, creating a cool parallax effect.

However, this only works when the background attachment is fixed. But in fixed position I cannot get the background image size to "cover" or "contain" the div without the image disappearing or resizing too large.

The only solution I found was to use repeat, which I don't want to do. I've also played around with background-position but that doesn't seem to work either, the image sometimes disappears or isn't in the same place across browsers

```
 .imgContainer{
            height:250px;
            border-top-right-radius:inherit;
            border-top-left-radius:inherit;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-image: url('test.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
                            background-attachment: fixed; /*If I remove this the image fills the div approriately, but the div below it doesn't scroll over it. */
```

}

HTML

```
    <div class="content">   
        <div class="imgContainer">
        </div> <!--ends imageContainer -->
        <div class="contentPosts">
                Content goes here and should scroll above the image rather than push it up
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript library [Skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), you will have a great control of your animations and the timing.

Check our these two tutorials to get you started with Skrollr:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)